# Borrar un registro de una base de datos en Oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Disculpen si la pregunta es tonta; pero soy nueva en base de datos y quisiera saber si me pueden apoyar, por favor. Mi duda es que tengo una base de datos en `Oracle` llamada (**Empresa**) con tablas no relacionales, en ellas manejo folios de personas y tengo distintas tablas como: **datos_generales**, **ocupacion**, **salud**, **estudios**, etc. Cada que me piden borrar un registro lo hago así:

```
DELETE FROM ocupacion WHERE folio=542;
```

Pero, ¿me gustaría saber sí es posible borrar el registro de todas las tablas de la base de datos en una sola consulta? En total tengo 40 tablas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo depende de como te hayan creado tu base de datos o tu modelo de entidad relacion, me explico: Si esta relacionada o tienes constraints la cuestion se hace mas civilizada.

Si te crearon los constraint asi:

```
alter table sample1 
   add foreign key (col1) 
references 
   sample (col2)
on delete cascade;
```

Si no lo tienes relacionad, el proceso tienes que hacer manualmente. Yo te recomiendo hacer un procedimiento y meter todas las tablas alli que deseas borrar de esta manera al momento de ejecutar el procedimiento borras todo de un solo golpe (como se dice coloquialmente en mi pais) esto puede ser un ejemplo sencillo:

```
create or replace procedure borrado_folio (p_folio IN varchar2)
is
Begin
delete from empresa.datos_generales where folio=p_folio;
delete from empresa.ocupacion where folio=p_folio;
delete from empresa.estudioswhere folio=p_folio;
//todas los datos de las tablas que vayas a borrar
end;
/
```

De esta forma creo, a mi parecer, te repito si no la tienes relacionada seria la mejor manera a mi parecer y te quitas eso de la borradera.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: si te sirvió de ayuda cierra el caso! y dame el visto bueno! saludos

Answer (score 0):

Podrías con un delete inner join así:

```
DELETE FROM tabla1
INNER JOIN tabla2 ON tabla1.id= tabla2.id
INNER JOIN tabla3 ON tabla1.id= tabla3.id
.
.
.
WHERE tabla1.id = 1;
```

Luego si tienes mas tablas solo tendrías que agregarlas como otros inner join

Comment: Me provoca este error:Error que empieza en la línea 1 del comando:
DELETE FROM ACTIVIDAD
INNER JOIN alcoholismo ON ACTIVIDAD.FOLIO = ALCOHOLISMO.FOLIO
WHERE ACTIVIDAD.FOLIO = 189
Error en la línea de comandos:2 Columna:1
Informe de error:
Error SQL: ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: falta el ; al final

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo de esta manera, DELETE (SELECT *
  FROM ACTIVIDADFISICA PF
    INNER JOIN alcoholismo PR
      ON PF.FOLIO = PR.FOLIO
  WHERE PF.FOLIO = 189
  AND PR.VISITA = 1); 
si quitó el "delete", el "select" si funciona, pero con el delete, provoca el error: Error SQL: ORA-01752: no se puede suprimir de la vista sin una tabla reservada mediante clave. The deleted table either had no key perserved tables,
           had more than one key-preserved table, or the key-preserved
           table was an unmerged view or a table from a read-only view.